# C++ using virtual functions

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

My program is outputting a strange set of numbers for each customer, and its not getting each customers' names. I'm not sure if I'm using the virtual functions correctly, as this is something relatively new to me conceptually.

The Compute_Bill() function is used in each class, because the Premium_Customer is using a different calculation for their bills than the normal Customer. I have commented out the cost for the calculations for each bill.

The main() function is just for building a list with different names and number of calls for each person, that way the program is supposed to show examples of the two different pricing plans.

Here is the output:

> Customer   owes 10 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 20.4 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes -7.02934e+114 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 20.4 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 10 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 20.4 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 10 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 20.4 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 10 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 20.4 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 10 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 20.4 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 10 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 20.4 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 10 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 20.4 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 10 dollars.
>
> Customer   owes 1.24244e+150 dollars.

And here is my program, from top to bottom it starts with Customer class, then Premium Class, and then the main:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// CUSTOMER CLASS
class Customer
{
private:
    double numCalls;
    string name;
    const double MONTH_FEE = 10;
    const double PER_CALL = .5;

protected:
    double bill;

public:
    Customer();
    Customer(string aName, double aCalls);
    virtual double Compute_Bill();
    string getName();
    void setName(string aName);
    double getCalls();
    void setCalls(double aCalls);
};

Customer::Customer()
{
}

Customer::Customer(string aName, double aCalls)
{
    aName = "";
    aCalls = 0;
}

string Customer::getName()
{
    return name;
}

void Customer::setName(string aName)
{
    aName = name;
}

double Customer::getCalls()
{
    return numCalls;
}

void Customer::setCalls(double aCalls)
{
    aCalls = numCalls;
} 

// Computing the bill for the Customer, uses
// bill = monthlyfee + (percallrate * numcalls)
// monthly fee = $10
// per call charge = .50
double Customer::Compute_Bill()
{
    bill = MONTH_FEE + (PER_CALL * numCalls);
    return bill;
}


// PREMIUM_CUSTOMER CLASS
class Premium_Customer : public Customer
{
private:
    double numCalls;
    string name;
    const double MONTH_FEE = 20;
    const double PER_CALL = .05;
    const double PER_MINUTE = .1;
    const double NUM_MINS = 4;

protected:
    double bill;

public:
    Premium_Customer();
    Premium_Customer(string aName, double aCalls);
    virtual double Compute_Bill();
    string getName();
    void setName(string aName);
    double getCalls();
    void setCalls(double aCalls);
};

Premium_Customer::Premium_Customer()
{
}

Premium_Customer::Premium_Customer(string aName, double aCalls)
{
    aName = "";
    aCalls = 0;
}

string Premium_Customer::getName()
{
    return name;
}

void Premium_Customer::setName(string aName)
{
    aName = name;
}

double Premium_Customer::getCalls()
{
    return numCalls;
}

void Premium_Customer::setCalls(double aCalls)
{
    aCalls = numCalls;
}

// Computing the bill for the Premium_Customer, uses
// bill = monthlyfee + (percallrate * numcalls) + (permin_callrate *   nummins)
// monthly fee = $20
// per call charge = .05
// per minute call rate = .10
// nummins = 4
double Premium_Customer::Compute_Bill()
{
    bill = MONTH_FEE + (PER_CALL * numCalls) + (PER_MINUTE * NUM_MINS);
    return bill;
}

// MAIN CLASS
int main () {
    Customer* list[18] ;
    list[0] = new Customer("John Dough", 20);
    list[1] = new Premium_Customer("Bob Dough", 20);
    list[2] = new Customer("Tim Dough", 30);
    list[3] = new Premium_Customer("Jane Dough", 30);
    list[4] = new Customer("Bill Dough", 40);
    list[5] = new Premium_Customer("Tom Dough", 40);
    list[6] = new Customer("Jim Dough", 50);
    list[7] = new Premium_Customer("Kane Dough", 50);
    list[8] = new Customer("Hon Dough", 60);
    list[9] = new Premium_Customer("Jill Dough", 60);
    list[10] = new Customer("Mary Dough", 70);
    list[11] = new Premium_Customer("Un Dough", 70);
    list[12] = new Customer("Sarah Dough", 80);
    list[13] = new Premium_Customer("Liz Dough", 80);
    list[14] = new Customer("Will Dough", 90);
    list[15] = new Premium_Customer("Mike Dough", 90);
    list[16] = new Customer("Brian Dough", 100);
    list[17] = new Premium_Customer("Kurt Dough", 100);
    for(int i=0; i<18; i++) {
        cout << "Customer " << list[i]->getName() << " owes "
        << list[i]->Compute_Bill() << " dollars." << endl;
    }
    // delete all the customers
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your constructors do not seem to be setting member variables correctly.  And same goes with a lot of your functions.  Try passing inputs by const/const& to functions that are supposed to set variables to catch the errors.

Comment: @RobertPrévost can you explain why they are wrong?

Comment: Take `Customer::Customer(string aName, double aCalls)` for instance.  Instead of setting the member variables, the temporary input variables are set instead.

Comment: @RobertPrévost oh! whoops haha. Thank you Robert.

Comment: @Yoyokolo don't hold currency in floating point types. You'll loose money!

Comment: Don't forget to declare a Virtual destructor in the base class to be sure the right destructor is called when you do   
delete pBasePtrPointingToDerivedObj;

Comment: Way too much code. You need a [MCVE] for questions here please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit but then if I don't put enough code to get my point across, how would anyone know exactly what my problem is? And the I get marked down for not explaining enough or giving enough code. And then I don't get an answer. I feel with as much activity as this post obtained, it was a pretty decent post. I will try to do better in the future though.

Comment: @Yoyokolo: Your [MCVE] is a _small_ program **that still reproduces the issue** (and thus gets your point across) but for which you have already done the legwork in removing all the parts of the program that do not contribute to the problem. This is a crucial, fundamental aspect of software debugging. You should really read the page I linked you to; it explains what _minimal_ and _complete_ means and how both are required :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thank you. I will look it over. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a lot of small mistakes. Your inheritance was basically fine, you just need to remove the parts you don't need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// CUSTOMER CLASS
class Customer
{
private:
    double numCalls;
    string name;
    const double MONTH_FEE = 10;
    const double PER_CALL = .5;

protected:
    double bill;

public:
    Customer();
    Customer(const string& aName, double aCalls);
    virtual double Compute_Bill();
    string getName() const;
    void setName(const string& aName);
    double getCalls() const;
    void setCalls(double aCalls);
};

Customer::Customer()
{
}

Customer::Customer(const string& aName, double aCalls)
{
    setName(aName);
    setCalls(aCalls);
}

string Customer::getName() const
{
    return name;
}

void Customer::setName(const string& aName)
{
    // you had this mixed up
    name = aName;
}

double Customer::getCalls() const
{
    return numCalls;
}

void Customer::setCalls(double aCalls)
{
    // this was mixed up too
    numCalls = aCalls;
}

// Computing the bill for the Customer, uses
// bill = monthlyfee + (percallrate * numcalls)
// monthly fee = $10
// per call charge = .50
double Customer::Compute_Bill()
{
    bill = MONTH_FEE + (PER_CALL * numCalls);
    return bill;
}


// PREMIUM_CUSTOMER CLASS
class Premium_Customer : public Customer
{
private:
    const double MONTH_FEE = 20;
    const double PER_CALL = .05;
    const double PER_MINUTE = .1;
    const double NUM_MINS = 4;

public:
    Premium_Customer();
    Premium_Customer(const string& aName, double aCalls);
    virtual double Compute_Bill();
    // the other methods are already inherited, no need to implement them again... 
};

Premium_Customer::Premium_Customer()
{
}

// no special logic here, just delegate to your base class constructor
Premium_Customer::Premium_Customer(const string& aName, double aCalls) : Customer(aName, aCalls)
{   
}

// Computing the bill for the Premium_Customer, uses
// bill = monthlyfee + (percallrate * numcalls) + (permin_callrate *   nummins)
// monthly fee = $20
// per call charge = .05
// per minute call rate = .10
// nummins = 4
double Premium_Customer::Compute_Bill()
{
    // no direct access to private customer variables here, used getCalls method instead
    bill = MONTH_FEE + (PER_CALL * getCalls()) + (PER_MINUTE * NUM_MINS);
    return bill;
}

// MAIN CLASS
int main() {
    Customer* list[18];
    list[0] = new Customer("John Dough", 20);
    list[1] = new Premium_Customer("Bob Dough", 20);
    list[2] = new Customer("Tim Dough", 30);
    list[3] = new Premium_Customer("Jane Dough", 30);
    list[4] = new Customer("Bill Dough", 40);
    list[5] = new Premium_Customer("Tom Dough", 40);
    list[6] = new Customer("Jim Dough", 50);
    list[7] = new Premium_Customer("Kane Dough", 50);
    list[8] = new Customer("Hon Dough", 60);
    list[9] = new Premium_Customer("Jill Dough", 60);
    list[10] = new Customer("Mary Dough", 70);
    list[11] = new Premium_Customer("Un Dough", 70);
    list[12] = new Customer("Sarah Dough", 80);
    list[13] = new Premium_Customer("Liz Dough", 80);
    list[14] = new Customer("Will Dough", 90);
    list[15] = new Premium_Customer("Mike Dough", 90);
    list[16] = new Customer("Brian Dough", 100);
    list[17] = new Premium_Customer("Kurt Dough", 100);

    for (int i = 0; i<18; i++) {
        cout << "Customer " << list[i]->getName() << " owes " << list[i]->Compute_Bill() << " dollars." << endl;
    }

    // delete all the customers
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe you have helped me before. Thank you once again. There's always the little things that get me like that. But I love to learn from my mistakes! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has Undefined Behavior since your constructors don't initialize the member fields. In particular the member `numCalls` is never initialized and it is used for the result of the method `Compute_Bill`.

Tools like valgrind point onto such errors: on your code, valgrind says

```
by 0x401C55: main (file.cpp:157)
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

In fact in your methods `setCall`, your should define

```
numCalls = aCall;
```

and not

```
aCall = numCalls;
```

which has no effect since it does affect a parameter.